# Spring Boot native image does not print logs when logback is configured with conditional

Tags: spring-boot, logback, graalvm-native-image, janino

## Summary

**Edit: The issue is only relevant from Spring Boot 3.0.0 to 3.0.2. It has been addressed in 3.0.3. See last section for details.**

I have a very simple Spring Boot 3.0.2 app with only janino as added dependency. When I use an if-else conditional in the logback configuration, then no logs are printed by logback when the application is run as a native image. However, printing with `System.out` works fine.

For compilation all reachability metadata has been provided that was given by the tracing agent when running the jar in the JVM. The application exits with a return code of 0.

Without an if-else condition, everything works as expected.

My questions are:

- Does anybody know how to fix this?
- What's the best approach to further troubleshoot this?

## The code

The `logback-spring.xml` with a conditional just to have a conditional:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <if condition='property("WITH_DEBUG").equalsIgnoreCase("true")'>
    <then>
      <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    </then>
    <else>
      <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    </else>
  </if>
</configuration>
```

The main (and only) class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LogbackIfElseApplication {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackIfElseApplication.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LogbackIfElseApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
    return args -> {
      LOG.info("Hello Logback!");
      System.out.println("Hello stdout");
    };
  }

}
```

My build script:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.18"
}

group = "foo"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.codehaus.janino:janino")
}
```

The full code is available [in this github repo](https://github.com/hpoettker/logback-if-else).

## The output

When run in the JVM without any further parameters, the output is as follows but shortened for conciseness:

```
$ java -jar build/libs/logback-if-else-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
INFO --- [main] foo.LogbackIfElseApplication  : Starting LogbackIfElseApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 5905
INFO --- [main] foo.LogbackIfElseApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
INFO --- [main] foo.LogbackIfElseApplication  : Started LogbackIfElseApplication in 0.946 seconds (process running for 1.352)
INFO --- [main] foo.LogbackIfElseApplication  : Hello Logback!
Hello stdout
```

When run as a native image, the full output is just

```
$ build/native/nativeCompile/logback-if-else
Hello stdout
```

## Edit

Thanks to [Andy's fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34315), the application no longer starts up without logging but fails early and logs

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Failed to parse condition [property("WITH_DEBUG").equalsIgnoreCase("true")] on line 3 org.codehaus.commons.compiler.InternalCompilerException: SNO: Generated compilation unit does not declare class 'SC'
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:261)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initializeFromAotGeneratedArtifactsIfPossible(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:212)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at foo.LogbackIfElseApplication.main(LogbackIfElseApplication.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Failed to parse condition [property("WITH_DEBUG").equalsIgnoreCase("true")] on line 3 org.codehaus.commons.compiler.InternalCompilerException: SNO: Generated compilation unit does not declare class 'SC'
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at foo.LogbackIfElseApplication.main(LogbackIfElseApplication.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Failed to parse condition [property("WITH_DEBUG").equalsIgnoreCase("true")] on line 3 org.codehaus.commons.compiler.InternalCompilerException: SNO: Generated compilation unit does not declare class 'SC'
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:261)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initializeFromAotGeneratedArtifactsIfPossible(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:212)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, Janino does not work when building a native image of your Spring Boot application. The problem is being tracked in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33758).